# Render html in angular js app from express js

Tags: angularjs, express

I am using angular on the front end and express js MongoDB on the backend, in server.js file of express application I am listening on port 3000

```
    var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server listening at http://' + server.address().address + ':' + server.address().port);
});
```

What I want is when I hit localhost:3000 my HTML page in angular js application should get render, which I achieved using

```
     app.get('/', function (req, res) {
                res.sendfile(__dirname + '/app/userlogin/userlogin.html');
});
```

When I hit localhost:3000 my HTML page is getting render but it is not including bootstrap files I am getting error 404 for scripts and links which I am adding in head tag but intelligence of vs2015 providing those bootstrap script files when I am trying to add them in my HTML, Following is my project structure and I have placed my bootstrap js and CSS files respectively in app -> js and app -> CSS

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need a `public_static` folder containing all your `frontend` code.
The express app should serve it with `express.static('')`

**server.js**

```
app.use(express.static('public_static'));
```

**Directory Structure**

```
-- server.js
-- public_static
           -- index.html ( Rename your userlogin.html )
           -- css
           -- JS ( Angular files )
                --- controllers
                --- directives
                --- services
```